# Sort list within list, preserve index?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have list where I would like to sort the elements within individual list.

> **Input**:
> [['AKO', 'CGN', 'G80', 'K34', 'KI4', 'Z82', 'C4P'],
> ['AKO', 'CGN', 'G80', 'K34', 'KI4', 'Z82', 'JL1'],
> ['AKO', 'CGN', 'G80', 'K34', 'KI4', 'Z82', 'K05'],
> ['AKO', 'CGN', 'G80', 'K34', 'KI4', 'Z82', 'U2K'],
> ['AKO', 'CGN', 'G80', 'K34', 'KI4', 'Z82', 'UE1'],
> ['AKO', 'CGN', 'G80', 'K34', 'KI4', 'Z82', 'B30', 'C4P'],
> ['AKO', 'CGN', 'G80', 'K34', 'KI4', 'Z82', 'B30', 'JL1'],
> ['AKO', 'CGN', 'G80', 'K34', 'KI4', 'Z82', 'B30', 'K05'],
> ['AKO', 'CGN', 'G80', 'K34', 'KI4', 'Z82', 'B30', 'U2K'],
> ['AKO', 'CGN', 'G80', 'K34', 'KI4', 'Z82', 'B30', 'UE1']]

> **Expected output**:
> [['AKO', 'C4P', 'CGN', 'G80', 'K34', 'KI4', 'Z82'],
> ['AKO', 'CGN', 'G80', 'JL1', 'K34', 'KI4', 'Z82'],
> ['AKO', 'CGN', 'G80', 'K05', 'K34', 'KI4', 'Z82'],
> .......
> .......
> ['AKO',  'B30', 'CGN', 'G80', 'K34', 'KI4', 'UE1', 'Z82']]

I can get this to work using a for loop, but would like to know if this can be vectorized for better performance.

Tried using np.sort but the individual elements within the list are not sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in the following way

```
res=[sorted(i) for i in yourList]
print(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

If your data is a pandas dataframe (as you have the pandas tag). You can indeed use [`numpy.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html). You will need to fill NaNs with some value, here I chose `'_'` to push NaNs at then end.

```
pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.fillna('_').values, axis=1))
```

output:

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
0  AKO  C4P  CGN  G80  K34  KI4  Z82    _
1  AKO  CGN  G80  JL1  K34  KI4  Z82    _
2  AKO  CGN  G80  K05  K34  KI4  Z82    _
3  AKO  CGN  G80  K34  KI4  U2K  Z82    _
4  AKO  CGN  G80  K34  KI4  UE1  Z82    _
5  AKO  B30  C4P  CGN  G80  K34  KI4  Z82
6  AKO  B30  CGN  G80  JL1  K34  KI4  Z82
7  AKO  B30  CGN  G80  K05  K34  KI4  Z82
8  AKO  B30  CGN  G80  K34  KI4  U2K  Z82
9  AKO  B30  CGN  G80  K34  KI4  UE1  Z82
```

Below is a more explicit example:

input:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list('ABCD')+[''], size=(5,5)))
```

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0     A  D  D  D
1  B  D  C     A
2  A     C  B  A
3  B  B  A  B   
4  D  A  D  A  C
```

output:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.replace('', '_').values, axis=1)).replace('_', '')
```

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  A  D  D  D   
1  A  B  C  D   
2  A  A  B  C   
3  A  B  B  B   
4  A  A  C  D  D
```

Comment: Please look at the desired output: yours does not solve the given problem.

Comment: OK, wrong axis, but otherwise correct

Comment: Much better.  :-)

Comment: There was a downvote there when I added mine.  When you corrected your answer, I removed the downvote.  My guess is that the first downvoter hasn't come back to see your correction.

Comment: While I won't/didn't DV this answer, others often DV answers to poorly presented questions. Also, questions such as this are typically DVed, closed, and deleted. As such you're wasting your time. SO is not here to answer every question, it is here to create a repository of **good** questions and answers, which can be used as a resource by others. If the quality of a question can be improved by editing, do so, otherwise it's advised to DV and vote to close. As you can see, all the answers have a DV.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you have a large list of lists, and plenty of processing power to use in parallel, there's no particular advantage to trying to vectorize this.  Since you are sorting each sub-list independently, you have little to gain from vectorization.  In fact, by importing `numpy` instead of simply using the native C implementation of `sort`, you're likely *losing* time with the package overhead.